# customize the method not allow response in flask

Tags: python, flask

in Flask Framework, define a route

```
@main.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

only can you use get method to request the index.html.
if I try to post some data to the index.html.
I got a method not allow webpage return. and that's correct.

but my problem is, Is there anyway I can customize the page by myself?
for example, return json data, instead of a method not allowed webpage??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create error handler

```
from flask import jsonify

@app.errorhandler(405)
def method_not_allowed(e):
    return jsonify({'error': 405}), 405
```

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/errorpages/

Comment: by the way where can I import the jsonify method?

Comment: from flask import jsonify